# For loop through a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with entries in column A and row 1:

[image]

It is possible with the following code to run a For-Loop through any amount of entries in column A:

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    '' Do whatever

Next i
```

But it is not possible to run a For-Loop through any amount of entries in row 1 with the code below and my question is why?

```
For i = 1 to Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).End(xlRight).Column

    '' Do whatever

Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is `xlToRight` not `xlRight`

Anyway I recommend to use

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

and

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

to find the last used column/row, because it is reliable even if there are blanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `xlRight` constant is not the correct one to use it in such a code. The correct one should be `xlToRight`.

But using this way is not the best one, if there is an empty cell in the row to be processed.

That's why, a better solution should be the next:

```
Sub testIterateThroughColumns()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).row
        'do what you need...
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually the issue is that `xlRight` indeed **does** exits (it is `-4152` and used for justification in the cell). If it would not exist and using `Option Explicit` you would at least get notified using a non defined variable but that is not the case. Since `xlToRight` is `-4161` the method `End` just doesn't know what to do with the value `-4152` of  `xlRight` and therefore throws the exception.

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ Ups... I recommended a verification way, but I did not verified it... :) I will change the way I describe the constant in discussion. Thanks!